# Awakening the Rinnegan

Tags: naruto

To awaken the Rinnegan, can you just get any Uchiha's and Senju's chakra, mix them together and get the Rinnegan? Or do you need Ashura's and Indra's in particular (i.e. their reincarnation's)?

Do you still need to go through some very sad or aggreviating situation to awaken it, or do you automatically get it the moment you mix the two chakras together?

Answer (score 2):

To get the rinnegan you need to have the mixture of the Ashura and Indra chakras. As Uchihas are descendants of some of them and the Senju of the others, the mixture of these also allows obtaining it. The clearest example is Madara who uses the chakra of the first Hokage to obtain it.

You do not need any more requirements, but it is not a trivial process Madara itself took more than 10 years to wake up the rinnengan.

**SPOILER ALERT**

> Sasuke has a special rinnegan is different and more powerful, this rinnegan is called Magatama Rinnegan. He obtained it by receiving the moon crescent, I think dark, side of Hagaromo's (the Sage of Six Paths) chakra.

Comment: so any Uchiha who takes a Senju's chakra can have it? So is it like, if you get Ashura and Indra's chakra directly it would be easier rather than their descendent's?

Comment: Yes, all Uchiha who take a senju chakra can obtain the rinnegan. We cannot know if using the ashura chakra or indra the process of obtaining the rinnegan it is easier or not, but saskue obtain it more fast than madara but is a diferent form.

Comment: then why did Madara take Hashirama's senju chakra to get himself the Rinnegan? Couldn't he take some other weaker Senju down and use his chakra instead?

Comment: @MartianCactus Once Indra and Asura's chakra mix, the new chakra is the sage of six paths chakra (AKA rinnegan). Sharingan might be a requirement though, and probably could be the source of Indra's chakra, but only indra's reincarnates ever even tried. Once awakend, it can be transplated to anyone though. Also Gawey, Its not the Supreme rinnegan, its the Rinne Sharingan. Though sasukes is slighly different, and sometimes called the sharrinegan.

Comment: @Ryan Yes Sharingan maybe was a requirement for obtain the Rinnegan. Also Saskue don't have Rinne Sharingan this is completly diferents this is the Rinnengan of  Kaguya (輪廻写輪眼, Literally meaning: Saṃsāra Copy Wheel Eye), Sasuke have the Supreme Sharigan (至高の輪廻眼, Shikō no Rinnegan), this Rinnegan have completly diferent patron in the eye, for more reference read the Sasuke Shinden Raikō-hen.

Comment: Could it be speculated that yamato if fitted with sharingan could gain the rinnegan

Answer (score 1):

Madara says when the powers of the Uchiha and Senju combine, the Rinnegan is awakened. Thats partly wrong. It's actually when one who possesses the Sharingan and is Indra's reincarnate, takes chakra of the Ashura's reincarnate, Hagoromo's chakra reforms in them. Thus awakens the Rinnegan. I'm assuming if an Ashura reincarnate took chakra from Indra's reincarnate, he'd unlock Rikudou Senjutsu? Not sure. Maybe he'd have a smaller amount of truth-seeking orbs as he only took a portion.

Answer (score 0):

You will need Uchiha DNA and Senju DNA and it will only work if the user is from the Senju or the Uchiha clan but Nagato Uzumaki had awakened it because Madara gave it to him when he was a child before he died by transplanting his eye to him.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true that you can take the chakra of ANY Senju. Only Indra and Ashura reincarnates. If the any Senju rule was real, Obito would have a Rinnegan without means of transplantation. Through the REINCARNATION process, only Uchiha, Uzumaki, and Senju can have Indra or Ashura. Firstly because the Uchiha is descendants of Indra, the Senju is descendants of Ashura, then Hashirama married an Uzumaki and made it possible for Uzumaki's to have a reincarnation in them too.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do it by implanting, if an incarnate of indra, the dna of the incarnate of asura. However, if you were an incarnate of asura, then you would have to implant the incarnate of indra's eyes, since you would need at least a mangekyou to evolve into the rinnegan. So if naruto implanted sasuke's right eye during the war, he will achieve rinnegan. The other way is being bestowed by hagoromo himself, which is how sasuke got his rinnegan, if he took naruto's dna, then he would get rinnegan in both eyes.

Comment: Shouldn't Asura mixing his chakra with Indra result in Six Paths Senjutsu? Asura and his lineage aren't known for any Visual Prowess at all, so it would make more sense if he got Six Paths power instead of Rinnegan. Not to mention that Asura and Naruto got Six Paths power when receiving chakra from Hagoromo.